# Filepond: how to allow camera input

Tags: camera, upload, filepond

I am using the Filepond upload plugin and would like to accept camera input on (manually it would be done by adding *capture="camera"*). I found the following explanation in the Filepond docs, but I am new to this and can't figure out exactly how to use their model. They say:

```
  // Allow media capture when value is set
  captureMethod: [null, Type.STRING],
  // - "camera", "microphone" or "camcorder"
```

I am at loss as to how exactly to implement this code, and what to write as the STRING value. Any help much much appreciated!!

Comment: Set the property `captureMethod` on the FilePond instance to "camera" should trigger FilePond to also set the "capture" attribute on the file input element.

Answer (score 0):

The `captureMethod` prop appears to accept the same values as the html `capture` attribute.

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `user` | The user-facing camera and/or microphone should be used. |
| `environment` | The outward-facing camera and/or microphone should be used |

Both values behaved as expected for me.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture
https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/properties/